# Interrogate ember-data model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Given a string like 'vehicle', I want to lookup this model and find all the field information.

For example, given a 'vehicle' string I want it to lookup the vehicle model and get the following.

```
FIELD                     TYPE          RELATED MODEL
registrationNumber        string        null
vehicleMake               belongsTo     manufacturer
versions                  hasMany       version
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution

```
var modelConstructor = this.store.modelFor('vehicle');
var attributes = Ember.get(modelConstructor, 'attributes');
var relationshipNames = Ember.get(modelConstructor, 'relationshipNames');
```